# Undefined reference ld error when using Windows <bluetoothapis.h>

Tags: c, gcc, bluetooth, ld

I am new to programming and want to work with the Windows BluetoothApi.h library in C. I've written smaller programs that reference header files I've created, but none of the APIs given by windows.

I am attempting to return information from a local bluetooth speaker to a terminal session on my PC. I've been referencing the [BluetoothFindFirstRadio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstradio) and [BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/ns-bluetoothapis-bluetooth_find_radio_params) documentation, as well as some posts on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945776/bluetooth-mac-address-in-c/27275004#27275004) to see some viable examples.  I believe I'm close to being able to compile but I keep getting an error about an undefined reference to the functions I'm calling that I do believe are in the BluetoothAPI.h header file.

From what I've seen, again on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272525/what-does-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-mean), it seems that it's possible that "there is not enough space left at \user\tmp"?

or

Looking at the [documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html) for ld, it may be possible I need to try to compile using a different command altogther?

```
PS C:\scripts\C_Lang\Bluetooth> gcc bluetest.c -o test
C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\cce0FxKH.o:bluetest.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `BluetoothFindFirstRadio@8'
C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\cce0FxKH.o:bluetest.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `BluetoothFindRadioClose@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h> //not sure if needed
#include <Ws2bth.h>  //not sure if needed
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include bluetoothapis.h>
//#include <bluetoothleapis.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib");

int main(void)
{

BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS btfrp; // structure
btfrp.dwSize = sizeof(btfrp);      // creating space in memory for parameters?
HANDLE hRadio;                     // not sure what a handle is, something similar to a pointer?
HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND hFind = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&btfrp, &hRadio);

// BluetoothGetDeviceInfo(hRadio, &pbtdi);

printf("Bluetooth test!");

BluetoothFindRadioClose(hFind);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my issue was not 100% my code, but about how I was attempting to compile my code. After looking further into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/using-bluetooth) I read the line, "Link only to Bthproprs.lib, and avoid linking to Ilprops.lib."  So, I don't fully understand why I would need to link, when I have a `#pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib");` but that is most likely due to my own ignorance.  I did notice the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426574/gcc-undefined-reference-to) post which helped clear up my ignorance of HOW to link the Bthproprs.lib library. So, my code didn't change, but my compile did, `gcc bluetest.c -o test -lbthprops`.

Now, to return something actually useful.